# Mock the return value of __call__

Tags: python, mocking

I'm writing unit tests in Python and I'd like to create a mock function that returns another mock (specified by me) when called.

Here's what I've tried:

```
my_mock = Mock()
fn = Mock()
fn.__call__ = Mock()
fn.__call__.return_value = my_mock
```

But when I call `fn()`, it returns a different mock, probably a default of some description.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also, is there a neater way to do this? I'd love to be able to write something like `fn = MockFunction(my_mock)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `return_value` argument:

```
mock_mock = Mock(return_value=my_mock)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I spent over an hour trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Pig https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class

Comment: Oh, I did, but guess I wasn't thorough enough!

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magic-methods), it's reasonable to expect your code to work. The docs do pretty much the same thing with the `__str__` method in an example, and it works:

```
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.__str__ = Mock()
>>> mock.__str__.return_value = 'fooble'
>>> str(mock)
'fooble'
```

However, this only works with *most* magic methods, and the exact list of which it works for is undocumented:

> Because magic methods are looked up differently from normal methods [[2]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id8), this support has been specially implemented. This means that only specific magic methods are supported. The supported list includes *almost* all of them. If there are any missing that you need please let us know.

`__call__` happens to be one of the magic methods that isn't on the list. Instead, you need to use the `return_value` attribute of the mock itself, or provide a `return_value` argument to the constructor.

```
fn = Mock()
fn.return_value = my_mock

# or

fn = Mock(return_value=my_mock)
```

Comment: That must have been where my confusion came from, thanks.